# Error in using div class in the header?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code which is irritating when displayed in the browser for a horizontal scroll bar appears when it isn't needed.

The horizontal bar is added to the browser when I add the two classes in the header.  Does anybody know what i have to tweak to get rid of the bar?  Many thanks in advance.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <link href = "style.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="header">
         <img src="uploads/brand.png">
         <p><p>
            <img src="uploads/rules.png">
            <div class="fbplugin">
               dsds
            </div>
            <div class = "counter">
               dsds
            </div>
         </p></p>
      </div>
      <div id = "divide"></div>
      <div id = "body">
         <div class = "container">
            stuff
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here is the  CSS:

```
#header {
   width: 100%;
   height: 140px;
}
#divide {
   width: 100%;
   height: 2px;
   background-color: red;
}
#body {
   width:100%;
   height:1000px;
   cursor:pointer;
}
.fbplugin{
   position: relative; top: -60px; left: 1000px;
}
.counter{
   position: relative; top: -130px; left: 1100px;
}
.container{
   width: 600px;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
   height: 500px;
   background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `position: relative;` on both `.fbplugin` and `.counter` to essentially move them to the right side of the header. By using `position: relative` you move an element from it's initial position but it still takes up the space of the initial position. This is why you have the scroll bars.

Instead `float` the two divs to the right so they don't span the length of your header and use margin/padding to position them vertically. This will get rid of the horizontal scroll bar.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AqLMY/2/

Comment: Cheers.  I see the benefit of that.